# Cache max-age and varnish ESI

Tags: 8, caching, proxies

I need to display a custom block on my homepage. This custom block retrieves some data that are not managed by Drupal. Since no event will happen in Drupal to say that those data have changed, the max-age cache property seems the way to go, and it's OK for me. The block appears exactly as expected, but the problem is thst the cache for this block seems to never expire. Actually, the block is never refreshed.

After researching, I found [Setting cache max-age to 0 has no effect on Block built using BlockBase?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/237777/setting-cache-max-age-to-0-has-no-effect-on-block-built-using-blockbase) that explains max-age cache property doesn't work as expected for anonymous requests. After adding the mentioned trigger, everything seemed to be all-right on my development environment.
Once on the production environment, it's the same as before: The block is never refreshed. Talking to the hosting provider, I was told that Varnish is used to cache the whole page, and I should use an ESI (*Edge Side Include*) to render this block with its own cache logic managed by Varnish.

I don't really know how to implement it in a clean way in Drupal. My first idea is to use a controller, render the block markup, and return in a response, forcing the needed cache-control header. This is the code I thought of for such controller.

```
$block_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');
$plugin_block = $block_manager->createInstance('my_block_id');
$buildedBlock = $plugin_block->build();
$renderedBlock = \Drupal::service ('renderer')->render ($buildedBlock);

$response = new Response(
    $renderedBlock,
    Response::HTTP_OK,
    array('content-type' => 'text/html')
);
$response->setSharedMaxAge(60);
return $response;
```

I feel it is a totally unclean way to do this. Does anybody a better approach to propose? Would my code work?

Comment: To clean it up a bit, you could use renderRoot() to render the final response and inject the services in the controller class. And uninstall the Internal Page Cache, it caches even uncacheable responses like this and you don't need it if you use Varnish.

Comment: Thank for putting me on the right track... I didn't knew about renderRoot() which seems more suitable in this use case. Of course I will inject services, it was just a rapid snippet ! ^_^  If I disable the internal page cache, I no longer need to use the page_cache_kill_switch trigger in my block right ?

Comment: Yes, don't trigger the kill switch, because this also kills the dynamic page cache, which you need if the block is in pages for authenticated users and as second level cache for varnish.

Comment: The block code is not part of the question, but you should consider to set for the block a max-age the same or higher as the s-maxage of the ESI response and ideally the block content is in a lazy builder and #create_placeholder is set to TRUE, because auto-placeholdering is not activated for max-age > 0 by default.

Comment: Thanks for this precision ... I've just had a look on #lazy_builder and #create_placeholder. Seems very interesting ... As far as I understand it, it seems really appopriate for my use case and I feel like it could replace the ESI trick ... I've tried to implement it, It does not seem to work for anonymous users ... Any idea?

Comment: No, this is not to replace the ESI trick, this is to make the backend side of this faster. I did think it was clear from the question that you have two delivery methods for the block content. The ESI include response is for anonymous traffic through varnish. Any other traffic gets the block content from drupal. You place the original block content in an ESI remove tag, so that varnish can replace it with the updated content.

Comment: Overall, you've asked two questions. 1) Would the code work? I think yes, you can probably make ESI work on your own like this or better wait for a contrib module that implements the ESI code already in the http kernel \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\Esi to have a more advanced delivery method. 2) Is there a better approach? Yes, see @Berdir's answer. A cron job to make the cache invalidation dynamic is the perfect workaround for the limitations of the current drupal caching. If I were you I would always prefer an answer from Berdir over some comments from a random drupal user :-)

Answer (score 3):

max-age 60s is pretty low for the frontpage. Does the data really update that frequently or is it just that it *could* update but usually it doesn't happen every minute?

One possible approach to solve this would be to fetch that external data on a cron job that runs every minute. If and only if you detect a change, you invalidate a cache tag, which invalidates your frontpage. This approach is interesting when the data does not actually change that often most of the time. Because your cache is valid as long as possible.

And it has the added benefit that you do not rely on the external system when users are actually accessing your frontpage. Your block simply delivers the data from state which you update in the cron job.

That said, if you do want to influence the max-age header, then you need to implement your own Response subscriber. You could also use a module like https://www.drupal.org/project/cache_control_override, but you have to carefully test different pages to see if it might disable caches in more places than you expect, e.g. a language switcher block can currently do that.

> And uninstall the Internal Page Cache, it caches even uncacheable responses like this and you don't need it if you use Varnish

If and only if you have cache tag invalidation configurated and integrated with Varnish. If not, my recommendation would be to use the internal page cache module and set the default external max-age to a very short time, e.g. 1 minute. Then varnish can cache responses for that long and will revalidate against the internal page cache after that time.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I agree 60 seconde is very short, but the remote data could potentially be updated that fequently. I agree with your approach consisting of invalidating cache tags only if the data changes, but unfortunately, the datas are updated remotely...  Actually, I don't want to invalidate the whole front page, but only this specific block. That's exactly what ESI are made for so it could be a good solution for me...

Comment: Yes, I understood that data is updated remotely, which is why I suggested you implemented a background job that checks that remote place, compares with temporarily stored local data and if changed, invalidated the output. Drupal doesn't support ESI out of the box and the overhead of getting that block on every request might be higher than you think. But drupal will automatically keep using caches of all other blocks and if you mark your block as uncacheable, it will use a lazy builder/big pipe placeholder for authenticated users